# How to change column name of an excel sheet using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a column named "%" in an Excel sheet. I want to rename it "Percentage" so that I can perform other operations such as line plot or scatter plot between Marks and Percentage.

I tried using the rename command. It's working, but it's not changing the column name permanently.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

new_data = pd.read_csv("Test Data.csv")
new_data.columns
```

It's giving the output as:

```
Index(['S. No.', 'Enrollment No.', 'Name', 'CLASS', '%', 'Marks'], dtype='object')
```

This code:

```
new_data.rename(columns = {"%":"Percentage"})

new_data.Percentage.plot(kind = "line", color = "g", alpha = 0.5, grid = True, label = "Percentage", linewidth = 2, linestyle = ":")
new_data.Marks.plot(color = "black", alpha = 0.5, grid = True, label = "Marks", linewidth = 2, linestyle = "-.")
plt.xlabel("Marks")
plt.ylabel("Percentage")
plt.show()
```

Also throws the error:

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Percentage'`

Comment: you need to assign it back `new_data=new_data.rename(columns = {"%":"Percentage"})` or make the change `inplace` : `new_data.rename(columns = {"%":"Percentage"},inplace=True)`

Comment: I tried new_data.%.plot. It also show error. For sure I cannot use % as column name. Please help.

Comment: According to your code you are not assigning the changed column names back to the dataframe. Check the above comment and then try.

Comment: Thanks @anky_91.. I should have assigned it. I simply wrote without assigning it back to the variable name. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Try this with the excel files:

`dataframe = pd.read_excel(file, header=None, skiprows=1, names=['abc','def'])`

for csv change `pd.read_excel` to `pd.read_csv`

Answer (score 0):

like anky_91 said: by default rename returns a new data frame with the new names: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

you can either reassign your data frame:

```
new_data = new_data.rename(columns = {"%":"Percentage"})
```

or you can set inplace to True

```
new_data.rename(columns = {"%":"Percentage"}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `inplace=True` parameter at your `new_data.rename(columns = {"%":"Percentage"})` command line.

Answer (score 0):

reassign the dataframe in to same varibale

```
new_data = new_data.rename(columns = {"%":"Percentage"})
```